# Redirect filenames to https and non-www with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using a htaccess to redirect any URL to https, non-www and with a trailing slash using this code:

```
# Force trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(go/.+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://example.com/$1/ [R=301,L]

# Force HTTPS and WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Basically, I want any URL that doesn't end with a trailing slash, doesn't have the form `/go/something` (I'm using those as affiliate links) and isn't a file, to redirect to a trailing slash. The first block should take care of that. The second block then just redirects any other possible URLs to https and non-www.

But if I go to http://www.example.com/image.png, no redirect happens. The first block does nothing, which is correct, but the second block should redirect it to https and non-www even though it's a file. What am I missing?

Comment: When you don't use the OR flag, RewriteConds are joined by an implicit AND - so both the conditions `%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https` and `%{HTTPS} off` would have to be true at the same time. Is that actually the case? Or did you mean them to be alternatives for different kinds of environments?

Comment: Whilst the second rule is not correct (as noted by CBroe above), it should still trigger a redirect for the stated scenario. Are you behind a front-end proxy?

Comment: Apparently I am behind a proxy, because if I omit the `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https` condition, I get in an endless redirect loop. @CBroe, the problem is that if I use the OR flag on the condition, I get to the same endless loop again. I'm actually not sure if I even need both conditions. I used to have only `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`, but then I switched to a new server and that didn't work anymore, so I added the Forwarded-Proto. Would it be safe to just delete the `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`?

Comment: "not sure if I even need both conditions" - You don't. If you are behind a proxy that handles your SSL then you don't need the `%{HTTPS} off` check (as you suggested). (Because if you are behind such a proxy then the `HTTPS` server var is always `off` and that condition is always successful.) Although this alone would not resolve the issue of "no redirect"? (It would seem to imply that `X-Forwarded-Proto` is `https` when it shouldn't be?) "then I switched to a new server" - is this another new server, or has this never worked?

Comment: I commented out the `%{HTTPS} off` condition and everything still works the same, like @MrWhite said. The funny thing is that if I use any URL that's not a file (with or without a trailing slash), the redirections work. Only filenames seem to cause a problem. Which makes no sense, since the second block doesn't look at filetypes.